# How to make a batch file to use Flex command line debugger?

Tags: actionscript-3, batch-file, apache-flex, flex4

After compiling my mxml file with the Flex 4.6 SDK.  I am trying to make use a Windows batch file to run the SWF file with the Flex debugger through the Flash Player projector content debugger.  I am able to start the debugger and a session using:

```
fdb File.swf
```

but then I need to type `continue` twice in the console to run the application.

I have tried using:

```
(echo run File.swf
echo continue
echo continue)| fdb
```

but that returns the error:

```
(fdb) Do you want to attempt to halt execution? (y or n) Not confirmed.
[SWF] c:\users\austin\documents\newproject\src\File.swf\[[DYNAMIC]]\1 - 674,784 bytes after decompression
[SWF] c:\users\austin\documents\newproject\src\File.swf\[[DYNAMIC]]\2 - 381,334 bytes after decompression
[trace] Warning: Ignoring 'secure' attribute in policy file from http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml.
The 'secure' attribute is only permitted in HTTPS and socket policy files.
See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files for details.
[SWF] c:\users\austin\documents\newproject\src\File.swf\[[DYNAMIC]]\3 - 1,148,91
9 bytes after decompression
Additional ActionScript code has been loaded from a SWF or a frame.
To see all currently loaded files, type 'info files'.
Set additional breakpoints as desired, and then type 'continue'.
```

My overall goal is to run the SWF file on a debugger through a batch file to see the return from `trace("functions")` in the command prompt.

Comment: Which version of Flex are you using ? Because using Flex 4.6, `fdb file.swf` run directly the swf file without any other interaction.

Comment: I am using Flex 4.6.  `fdb file.swf` will run the swf file with the normal flash player, but I am trying to use the Flash Player projector content debugger.  Sorry I didn't specify that earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fdb -unit` Worked!

Here is the final working code:

```
(echo run File.swf
echo continue
echo continue)| fdb -unit
```

Solution found at https://forums.adobe.com/thread/774121?tstart=0